# Conditional styling with CSS modules in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, css-modules

Im trying to set the visibility of a button with conditional classnames but typescript is giving me this error:

```
Type '{ className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

Is there any way to go around this?

My code:

```
<Reset className={resetVisible ? styles.reset_visible : ''}></Reset>
```

Comment: What is `<Reset>`? What props does it take?

Comment: It does not take any props, its just a component with a reset icon

Comment: Yes but as it is not an html element, and is a custom React component instead, you have to specify that it can receive the attributes of an html element. Based on the error I'm assuming you already did that, but it seems that the provided type is incorrect.

Comment: I did not do that. That should be the problem than :D

Comment: Alright, please see if [this](https://thewebdev.info/2022/03/20/how-to-add-types-for-rest-props-in-react-and-typescript/) helps :)